# How can I detect when a node is changed from 'Published' to 'Unpublished'?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, hooks

In [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7), I can easily tell the 'status' of a node (whether it's published or not) after it's been updated.

However, is there an easy way to check to see if the updated node *was* published, but now is not? (Or vice-versa)?

I think Rules might have some condition for 'node value has changed' or something along those lines, but I'd like to do this programmatically.

I found [this issue by fago](http://drupal.org/node/651240) (developer of Rules) on drupal.org that seems to deal with this in Drupal 7, but a nice explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Nevermind. After reading through the issue linked above (especially [comment #38](http://drupal.org/node/651240#comment-3769352)), I found that the $node object (any entity, actually) stores the 'original' cached copy in $entity->original.

So, I wanted to detect whether a node changed from 'status = 1' to 'status = 0' (this happens when the node is unpublished), and the following code does this:

```
<?php
function custom_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    // Act on the unpublishing of an article.
    if ($node->original->status == 1 && $node->status == 0) {
      // Do something here.
    }
    // Act on the publishing of an article.
    if ($node->original->status == 0 && $node->status == 1) {
      // Do something here.
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've gotta stop answering my own questions ;-)

Comment: why? It was still helpful to me, worth a +1 ;-)

Comment: Heh, this is about the 10th time I've landed on my own answer in Google results. Future me thanks past me for answering :)

Comment: Above code is not going to work if you are using revisioning module

Comment: For the record, this could not be not working for status + workflow + translation, I had to use `$entity->original->getTranslation($lng)->status->value == 0 && $entity->getTranslation($lng)->status->value == 1`

Answer (score 1):

`node_save()` contains the following code.

```
  try {
    // Load the stored entity, if any.
    if (!empty($node->nid) && !isset($node->original)) {
      $node->original = entity_load_unchanged('node', $node->nid);
    }
  }
```

`entity_load_unchanged()` loads the entity (in this case the node) from the database; it returns the entity object before any changes made from the running modules.

The code is executed before any pre-save, and update hooks.

```
module_invoke_all('node_presave', $node);
module_invoke_all('entity_presave', $node, 'node');

//... 

node_invoke($node, $op);

// Save fields.
$function = "field_attach_$op";
$function('node', $node);

module_invoke_all('node_' . $op, $node);
module_invoke_all('entity_' . $op, $node, 'node');
```

In those hooks, it is possible to see the node properties before any change in `$node->original`, for example with `$node->original->status`.