# After publish node send email to someone

Tags: 7, emails

Let's say i have a custom module in D7 , i want to add a feature to  this .

the feature is : when a user publish a node send an email to someone .

```
   function sending_email_node_update($node){
    if (isset($node->original->status) && $node->original->status == 0 && $node->status == 1){
        drupal_mail('sending_email','email_action','soheilsadeghbayan@yahoo.com',language_default());
  }
}

function sending_mail_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
switch ($key){
    case 'sending_email_node_update':
        $message['subject'] = t('this is my action report');
        $message['body'][] = t('this is a reporting from sending email made by soheil') ;

        break;
}
}
```

Could you please help me how to do this ?

Comment: you problem is in key, you set key `email_action` but in case statement you work with `sending_email_node_update` .  :)

Comment: thank you , i changed the key in drupal_mail to sending_email_node_update but nothing changed @Zhilevan !!!!

Comment: do u mean put  `case 'sending_email_node_update':` to `case 'email_action':` and not work?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: It is strange , It had to work :(

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to do this. You'll have to watch a few tutorials to wrap your head around rules, but you won't have to re-invent the wheel or maintain any code.

If you need the custom module solution, check these out.

Check if node is being published: 
[How can I detect when a node is changed from 'Published' to 'Unpublished'?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-can-i-detect-when-a-node-is-changed-from-published-to-unpublished)

Then, use [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) to send your emails.

Comment: Yes, Rules is a good solution here. Note you can export your Rule configuration with your custom module, if required, using [`hook_default_rules_configuration`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_default_rules_configuration/7)

Comment: Thx guys , yes i know it's possible with Rules module , but i want to practice with coding .  
Thx

Comment: I wouldn't use Rules. If you can code, you should code. I used to think Rules was the answer, but in reality it's just a load of cruft that's complicates what you're really trying to do. Also, we have a way for revisioning code that's far less complicated that hook_default_rules_cofiguration: git.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the [Message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145)? I think [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) is sometime is overrated:

1. To much work to set up the rule.
2. Why to use a large module like rule when you can use your own module and deal with the situation in 20 +- lines of code?
3. How would people become module developer and contribute code back to the community if they need rules to do simple action when a entity is updated?

And this how you can send email to a user when a node is updated in 4 simple steps:

1. Download the module [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) and [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify) and enable them.
2. Create a Message Type with the text your want to put in the mail.
3. Create your own module or just export the Message with [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) (this could be your module).
4. Use the next gist in your module: https://gist.github.com/RoySegall/8369317

This is how that gist looks like:

```
/**
* Implements hook_node_update().
*/
function hook_node_load($node) {
  if ($node->original->status == $node->status) {
    return;
  }

  $message = message_create(MESSAGE_NAME, array('uid' => SOME_UID));
  message_notify_send_message($message);
}
```

The [Message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145) is great. [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) and Drupal Commons are using them, why not you to?

Comment: HI @Roy Segall because i do want to create it programaticlly,
i know it's possible with these stuff but this kind of practicing

Comment: +1 for the "message" part of your answer, though I don't really disagree with what you wrote about Rules.

Comment: Well.. We are artists of websites. just like an artist have several tools to paint(oil based colors, water based, different brushes etc., etc.) we have different tools to create sites. 

I don't like rules but if you like rules - you go girl :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you, use [`hook_node_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) something like this in your custom module run when the node be published

```
function MYMODULE_node_update($node){
  if (isset($node->original->status) && $node->original->status == 0 && $node->status == 1){

       put your code here to run after node publish

  }
}
```

Comment: I do appreciate it , i'll give it a try and let you know  
THX ;)

Comment: @Soheil you welcome, I glad to help you Soheil ;)

Comment: i edited my post . is this true ? can you please help me out ?

Comment: @Soheil  , please dont change your question completely,It's convert all answer to waste  :(

Comment: put this comment below my question not here if it's about my question not your answer  
  
by the way i have not changed my question like 10 days and the last person who answered it was you ...  
so don't be so hard ;) i'll put the right answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

while calling drupal_mail function the second argument is key and you are sending key as **email_action**  and in you hook_mail you are checking for **sending_email_node_update** instead of **email_action**.. once you fix this you will be able to catch that mail just before being sent.. do your stuff there and done..

one more thing i would suggest you is check out drupal **RULES** module https://drupal.org/project/rules ...
The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events..

Comment: thank you , i changed the key in drupal_mail to sending_email_node_update but nothing changed @Ashish Sajwan